# No known class method for selector 'testPrint' while calling swift singleton function in objective c function

Tags: objective-c, swift, singleton

I have a swift singleton file where I have a function to be called, but when I call it in my objective-c file I get the error.

```
class TestSimulator {

    static let testSim = TestSimulator()

    @objc func testPrint(){

        print("test print works")
    }

}
```

in objective c file

```
[[TestSimulator testSim] testPrint];
```

I import the TestSimulator file using

```
@class TestSimulator;
```

Comment: @class TestSimulator; is not an import. it is a forward declaration

Comment: Did you read “Using Swift Classes in Objective-C” in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1187415? You need to `#import "<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h"`

Comment: 'TestSimulator-Swift.h' file not found